# Displaying content from 2 models on a single Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am working with my first Django project and I have printed my first template tag using a view onto my page template. I'd like to display some other database values on my page, but repeating the same process seems wrong.

Here are my two models:

```
class Drink(models.Model):
    drink_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    strength = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.drink_name


class status(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    health = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    strength = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    charisma = models.IntegerField(default=50)
```

And my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Drink
from .models import status

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    served_drinks = Drink.objects.order_by('strength')
    context = {'served_drinks': served_drinks}
    return render(request, 'tavern/index.html', context)
```

And my template:

```
  Hello {{ user.get_username }}, welcome to the tavern.

  <br><br>

  <div class="card-panel teal lighten-3">Grab a drink from the bar</div>
  {% if served_drinks %}
      <ul>
      {% for drink in served_drinks %}
          <li>{{ drink.drink_name }} with a strength of {{ drink.strength }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  {% else %}
      <p>No drinks are available.</p>
  {% endif %}
```

Which returns:

```
Hello admin, welcome to the tavern. 

Grab a drink from the bar
Water with a strength of 0
Wine with a strength of 3
Ale with a strength of 5
Black Ale with a strength of 9
```

As you can see I've printed out my `served_drinks` object in the template, but I also want to print out data from the `status` model on this page too.

I've tried simply adding `{{ status.health }}` to the template but this does not work. Should I be adding extra information to the `index` view? If so, what if I want to show this information on many pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using the `render` shortcut, you can add whatever you want to the `context` dict:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    served_drinks = Drink.objects.order_by('strength')
    context = {
        'served_drinks': served_drinks,
        'status': Status.objects.get(user=request.user),
    }
    return render(request, 'tavern/index.html', context)
```

Then you can use `{{ status.health }}` in the template. Note the `login_required` decorator is used so that only logged-in users can access the view, otherwise the `Status.objects.get()` would fail for anonymous users. I would also rename your model from `status` to `Status`, so that you do not confuse the `Status` model with `status` instances.

However, you don't actually need to add `status` to the context in this case. You can follow the one-to-one field backwards from `user` to `status`:

```
{{ user.status.health }}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alasdair - I am seeing the error `Status matching query does not exist.`, do I need to add a line such as `status = status.objects.all().first()` as described in the other answer? Is this required?

Comment: That means that there isn’t a status for that user in the database. If you do `Status.objects.first()` it will stop the error, but the status will probably be unrelated to the user.

Comment: Aha, you're correct! Assumed creating the fields would add them to the DB but it did not. I actually had to change the values to get them to fire into the DB!

Answer (score 5):

You should pass your status instance to the context of the view as well. For example, let's get a first instance of status model in database:

```
def index(request):
    served_drinks = Drink.objects.order_by('strength')
    status = status.objects.all().first()
    context = {'served_drinks': served_drinks, 'status': status}
    return render(request, 'tavern/index.html', context)
```

Now, you can use `{{ status.health }}` in your template.

Also, try to start your model names with capital letters. So, model Status is better than status. It's just good practices.

Comment: Thank you, when I use your code I still see `Health:   ` on my rendered page when calling `{{ status.health }}`. When I add simply `{{ status }}` I see `Health: None`, what am I missing here? @Olzhas